# Stata: Transposing data rows duplicated to column

Tags: stata, panel

I am trying to rearrange the identification data (ID) that is duplicated. Each ID is duplicated, because the person uses more than one drug type.

[image]

Each code represents the name of the drug and in each column titled (`drug1`; `drug2`; `drug3`) there is information if the person takes (1) or does not take (0)

Into:

[image]

As the code is the name of the drug (`drug1= code 17`; `Drug2 = code 5`; `Drug3 = code 3`), when remodeling the code column it would not appear in the database
I think using `reshape` will not achieve the result I expect.
I would be very grateful for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your rules or example but this may help.

```
clear 
input ID Code Drug1 Drug2 Drug3 
1  5 0 1 0
1 17 1 0 1
2 17 1 0 1
2 5 0 1 0
2 3 0 0 3
end 

collapse (max) Drug?, by(ID)
list 

foreach v of var Drug? {
    replace `v' = `v' > 0 
}

list 

     +----------------------------+
     | ID   Drug1   Drug2   Drug3 |
     |----------------------------|
  1. |  1       1       1       1 |
  2. |  2       1       1       1 |
     +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
There is still a quastion. Should I run replace only with "V" in the DO, or should I replace it with some variable?

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t understand what else  you’re asking.